# Has anyone had any experience with Editsprings?

Tags: peer-review, email, language, copy-editing

I received the following email from a company called Editsprings:

> Dear Prof./Dr. XXX,
>
> It is our great honor to write you this email. Here is an invitation about working as a part-time editor from EditSprings. This is a remunerated position. Your responsibility is to help non-native English speaking scholars to improve their English writing and the overall quality of their manuscripts.
>
> Our company, EditSprings, is an academic service provider established in China, and we hold offices in Wuhan China and Boston US. Our aim is to help Chinese researchers to publish their academic research papers in SCI, EI and SSCI journals by providing services such as translation, English language editing, academic editing, peer review and journal recommendation. More than 500 editors/reviewers, working as doctors, engineers, scientists or university instructors for reputable institutions across the United States, Britain, Canada, Australia and so on, are collaborating with us to help a continuously increasing number of researchers to overcome their English language barrier. Meanwhile, our company has helped more than 10,000 Chinese researchers to publish their papers in diverse English academic journals.
>
> Programs for your choice
>
> You can work on one or more programs listed below.
>
> Language editing: revise the manuscript for language-related aspects only, such as grammar, vocabulary usage, spelling, punctuation, sentence structure, etc.
>
> Academic editing: revise the manuscript regarding academic logicality, content organization, result analysis and language; make sure the manuscript meets publication standards
>
> Peer Review: assess the overall manuscript and provide opinions/suggestions to each section; evaluate the manuscript’s suitability to the author’s intended journal and recommend three journals most suited to the manuscript if possible
>
> Journal recommendation: assess the overall manuscript based on criteria like research significance, novelty, preciseness and language quality; recommend three journals most suited to the manuscript
> If you are interested in this position, please fill up the following registration form and send us your CV. Also, please specify which program interests you the most.
>
> If you want to learn more about our company, please feel free to consult this website, and here is the link: https://www.editsprings.com/en/
>
> Please do not hesitate to contact us if you have any questions or concerns. We are looking forward to hearing from you soon.
>
> Thank you very much.
>
> Best regards,

As the email says, this company is retributing researchers for providing some help with manuscripts for their customers. Honestly, I wouldn't mind getting paid for reviewing papers/helping to improve the quality of papers, since I review papers for free all the time. However, I don't know if this company is legit/reliable. Has anyone had any experience with them?

Comment: It should be spam, be careful.

Comment: I am also curious about this, have you followed through with them?

Comment: @HermanToothrot no, I sent them an email asking for some more information and they never replied back

Comment: Just received an email from them but I immediately thought it was a scam